# Many Japanese authors use $o\left(x^n\right)$ and don't use $O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$. Any reason?

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question, asymptotics

Many Japanese authors write the following formula in their calculus books:

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+o\left(x^n\right).$$

I wonder why they don't write the following formula in their calculus books:
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+O\left(x^{n+1}\right).$$

If $f=O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$, then $f=o\left(x^n\right)$.
So, $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$ gives us more information than $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+o\left(x^n\right)$.

So, I think $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+O\left(x^{n+1}\right)$ is superior to $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\dots+\frac{1}{n!}x^n+o\left(x^n\right)$.

Any reason?

By the way, Mathematica uses $O$-notation.

Comment: Little o notation and big O notation have essentially different meanings. For instance, $O(x^{3/2})$ is $o(x)$ but is not $O(x^2)$.

Comment: @TravorLZH I think the point is "because they mean different things, and the more restrictive version is true, why say the less restrictive version?"

Comment: @TravorLZH Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Using little $o$ instead of capital $O$ is maybe a question of education : remain modest in any circumstance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that in the Taylor series of $e^x$, either version of the formula is true, and so the $O(x^{n+1})$ version is slightly better.

However, in general, [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) only guarantees an $o(x^n)$ error in the degree-$n$ truncation of the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$, under the assumption that $f$ is differentiable $n$ times at $0$. To get an $O(x^{n+1})$ error, we need $f$ to be differentiable $n+1$ times.

We cannot guess at the motivations of "many Japanese authors" (and I question whether there are many of them, and whether Japanese authors are more likely to do this). However, one plausible argument for using $o(x^n)$ is for consistency: we can use that error term in all cases, rather than use $o(x^n)$ some of the time and $O(x^n)$ some of the time.

Comment: The key here is $O(x^{n+1})$ requires more derivability than $o(x^n)$. I can't speak for Japanese authors, but depending on what one wants to assume and to get, one or the other is better, and it's not obviously $O$ (I have seen tricky exercises where the assumptions are made just tight enough that one can use $o$, but not $O$).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Misha Lavrov, Thank you very much for your answer.